# CS-Cart editing .tpl files and cache refresh

Tags: caching, e-commerce, cs-cart

I am doing some simple hooks and some more advanced ones for a customer. (CS-Cart 2.1.4)
I have 2 websistes (production site and test site)...the two environment are not exactly the same, sadly

If I edit anything in a TPL file in the test environment, I simply save+upload on FTP and the edits are immediately visible on test website...

If I do the same edits on production environment, then save+upload on FTP, nothing changes on the storefront...

I understand it has probably something to do with template caching, and i should run mysite.com/admin.php?cc

The problem is I am the new webmaster, the old one left arguing with customer, I don't know what he has left exactly and I am afraid of refreshing production cache and "destroying" everything...(the website makes about 1M Euros/year...just to tell you what...). what if he has made some changes on the template and never refreshed cache???

Any suggestion on how to see my edits to those damned .tpl files???

Answer (score 1):

To avoid clearing cache manually (by &cc) you should to change the Store mode.

Open the Admin area (any page) and look at the page bottom: http://screencast.com/t/aS2aG7oYTg
Your Store is working in Live mode and the Smart Template Engine does not check the changes in file. Click once this link and the Store mode will be changed to the "Development". Cache will be updated automatically.

P.S. You can delete var/cache and var/compiled. Store will not be destroyed :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, by creating a clone of the Virtual Machine , editing there, and then replicated edits on main production site after being 100% sure there were no issues when clearing the cache ;-)